# Block a specific app from updating in the Microsoft store

Tags: blocking, auto-updates, microsoft-store

Well, i know that i can disable all automatic updates in the Microsoft store, but what about blocking just a single app from doing the update. The problem with manually updates in Microsoft store is, as soon as i perform a manual check for available updates, the downloads still start automatically for all apps. No way i can intercept that and only update the apps that i want.

So do you people know any way to just block a specific app from updating via the store?

Comment: Uninstall any Store apps you do not want or need. Then these apps will not update. All the other installed apps will update. This is generally not a problem on any of my Windows 10 machines.

Comment: While this is true, my problem is that i want a specific app to stay on its previous version, because the latest update brings a feature i don't want and breaks my working routine. so uninstalling is not an option.

Comment: Microsoft apps that are installed do not stay at older versions. I do not know any way to do this (6 years with Windows 10). Store apps do not have the control that can be had with Windows 10.

Comment: ok. i feared that it will be like this, since i didn't find a single solution after hours of google. thanks for your time!

Comment: I did post an answer for you (and for others with the same question).  Hopefully you will acknowledge the answer.

Comment: Allegedly there's a Group Policy/registry key that prevents background updates for UWP apps that are sideloaded, but when I added it MS Store still updated the app to the latest version, so....
https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_11_2022&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Appx::DisableBackgroundAutoUpdates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Microsoft Store apps, you can uninstall any apps you do not need and then these, of course, will not update.

Any remaining apps that are installed will update always.

Store apps do not have the granularity or flexibility of Windows 10 itself.

So you will need to accept the way it works.

I trust this helps you.

Comment: Just wanted to note that the Microsoft Store is insisting on updating Notepad of all apps. I'm unable to find a way to block updating this specific app which is frustrating given it's an app installed as part of the OS rather than the Store.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with whiteboard - the new version is just a mistake of nature.
So, here's what I did:

- deactivated auto-updates in store
- when updating, I ALWAYS update under personal scrutiny
- BUT - because I'm human and make mistakes (and Murphy's Law always apply) - I have the installer for the old whiteboard - and when I find that it has been updated, I just run the old app installer and roll it back.

So, all you have to do is crawl the net and find your old app installer.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I'm curious, what is wrong with Whiteboard, and what version is your "rollback" version? And when you want to roll back, do you first have to uninstall the newer Whiteboard version, or can you just run the old updater when the new version's still installed?